Порядок сортировки при повторяющихся значениях в оконных функциях
Есть набор данных следующего формата:
id, val
(0, val1) ---- equivalent val
(1, val1) ---- equivalent val
(2, val1) -- equivalent id ---- equivalent val
(2, val2) -- equivalent id
(3, val3)

Я использую запрос вида: select lag(val) over (order by id) from Table и сталкиваюсь с непредсказуемым значением оконной функции в силу повторяющегося значения в столбце сортировки.
Дублирующихся значений id может быть только 2 подряд.
Мой конечный запрос сводится к сравнению значения val текущей с val предыдущей строки, то есть что-то вроде select case when lag(val) over (order by id) = val then 'result' else 'another result' from Table
Была идея проверять значение сразу 2 строк, чтобы "перекрыть" рандомную сортировку:
select case when lag(val, 1 , null) over (order by id) = val or lag(val, 2, null) over (order by id) = val then 'result' else 'another result' from Table
Но это решение не подошло в силу того, что значения val могут повторяться и дать псевдопожительный результат (см. id = 0, id = 2), тогда как меня интересует строго предыдущая строка.

Подскажите, я правильно понимаю, что не указывая второй столбец для сортировки, нет возможности ни предугадать значение, ни повлиять на него иными средствами?
Если есть идеи, как решить мою задачу, буду рад.


А в order нельзя сразу два столбца указать: over (order by id, val)? Может в данном случае это не применимо, но обычно в таких случаях просто по нескольким полям сортируют, чтобы обеспечить устойчивость сортировки.

К сожалению, нельзя( в этом то вся и загвоздка

Да, порядок вывода строк - на усмотрение БД. Самым разумным вариантом видится изменение таблицы и добавление туда отдельного столбца типа version. При вставке записей проверять наличие такого id. select count(*) into cnt from table where id=2; или select max(version) + 1 into cnt from table where id=2; ну и далее insert into table (id, val, cnt)

К сожалению, нельзя - и вот с этого места поподробнее. Потому как Постгресс прекрасно поддерживает сортировку по нескольким полям. Мой конечный запрос сводится к сравнению значения val текущей с val предыдущей строки Понятие "предыдущая строка" существует строго после того, как определён порядок сортировки, значение выражения которого уникально на всём наборе записей. До тех пор пока это условие не выполнено (а для указанного ORDER BY id - оно как раз не выполняется), никакого детерминированного "предыдущая строка" нет, и сервер волен использовать любую из группы.

я правильно понимаю, что не указывая второй столбец для сортировки, нет возможности ни предугадать значение, ни повлиять на него иными средствами? Абсолютно правильно.

@Akina , "к сожалению, нельзя" с точки зрения бизнес-логики запроса, имелось ввиду

с точки зрения бизнес-логики запроса То есть вы сейчас сказали, что у вас бизнес-логика попросту кривая. Если требование уникальности не соответствует бизнес-логике, то ей, выходит, пофиг, какая из записей будет считаться "следующей". Но вам на это не наплевать - значит, косяк именно в логике.

@Akina , можно сказать и так. Факт в том, что данные у меня ровно в указанном виде. Логически подразумевается сортировка по id (на сама деле там даты, но не суть) и проверка "предыдущих" строк согласно сортировке по id + сравнению val (в зависимости от равенста/неравенства val, с учётом сортировки, определяется какая строка всё-таки является "предыдущей"). Проблема в недетерменированности сортировки, которую нужно как-то обойти

Гм... Вопрос. Есть записи (id=1,val=2), (2,1), (2,3). Ну понятно, что при сортировке по id первая запись и есть первая... но вот из оставшихся - какая вторая, а какая третья? и почему?

Сильно упрощая, логика следующая "если id меньше на 1 и val равны, то строка считается предыдущей". То есть, для (2, val1) предыдущей должна стать (1, val1)
з.ы. подчеркну, что "id меньше на 1" - это упрощение, тк в моих данных используются даты, а не int'ы и их интервалы непредсказуемы. Посему, пытался изначально зайти через оконки

После написания предыдущего комментария пришла идея проRankовать мои даты и попробовать свести задачу к примеру буквально из текущего запроса. Возможно, это позволит гибче смотреть в "предыдущую" строку
Мысль пока недодумана, мб толку и не будет

Вы не ответили на именно мой вопрос. Я показываю три записи - расположите их по требуемому порядку и поясните, почему так. "если id меньше на 1 и val равны, то строка считается предыдущей" Это как раз более-менее понятно... а вот если НЕ равны? как у меня в показанных записях... PS. Не забывайте добавлять @username - без него уведомления не приходят.

@Akina , этот кейс можно определить как "another result" в теле вопроса, тк val id=2 не равны val id = 1. В данный момент, оно нас не интересует

"Я подумаю об этом позже." Не, так не делается... Сперва строите алгоритм, описывающий все возможные сочетания, и только потом его программируете.

@Akina , вероятно, я некорректно выразился. Алгоритму важны только случаи равенства. Когда val предыдущей != val текущей, делать ничего не нужно

Какое может быть "делать ничего не нужно"?? Вы используете обращение к предыдущей строке? используете. Это тоже "делать". И это должно выполняться детерминированно.

Ответ на заданный вопрос

не указывая второй столбец для сортировки, нет возможности ни предугадать значение, ни повлиять на него иными средствами?

Можно сортировать по не по значению, а по служебной колонке ctid. Это даст стабильный порядок строк.
Но в общем случае значения во втором столбце могут идти не по порядку.
Например:
id, val
(0, val1)
(1, val1)
(2, val1)
(2, val2)
(3, val3)
(4, val3)
(4, val2) -- уменьшение val
(5, val2)

Тогда сортировка по значению не будет работать, и никакая обычная сортировка не поможет.
Алгоритм сортировки получается рекурсивным. Чтобы отсортировать две строки с id = i и определить, какая из них первая, а какая последняя, — надо сравнить их значения со значением, указанным в последней строке с id = i - 1.
Для данной задачи явная сортировка вообще не нужна, достаточно помечать, какая строка последняя, чтобы продолжать рекурсию от неё.
На больших объёмах данных рекурсия сильно неоптимальна. Как указали в комментариях, бизнес-логика кривая. Либо структура данных.
Тем не менее, технических проблем написать такой SQL нет:
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    val,
    null as result,
    true as use_later_flg
  FROM t
  WHERE id = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    t.id,
    t.val,
    case when t.val = r.val then 'result' else 'another_result' end as result,
    t.val <> r.val or count(*) over () = 1 as use_later_flg
  from
    r
    join
    t
    on r.id + 1 = t.id
    and r.use_later_flg
)
SELECT
  id,
  val,
  result
FROM r;




id
val
result




0
val1
null


1
val1
result


2
val1
result


2
val2
another_result


3
val3
another_result


4
val3
result


4
val2
another_result


5
val2
result



Предполагается, что id последовательные, без пропусков.
Вот это требование не реализовано:

Алгоритму важны только случаи равенства. Когда val предыдущей != val текущей, делать ничего не нужно

Без примера непонятно, что имеется в виду. Но полагаю, что добавить фильтры в код не будет проблемой.
Демо: https://dbfiddle.uk/StAEiHb_
Ответ с учётом комментария про даты
Следует изменить структуру данных, отслеживать и сохранять также время. Тогда получится медленно меняющееся измерение.
Также, если значение не меняется, то повторять его каждый день незачем:
begin_ts, val
(01.01 00:00, val1)
(02.01 12:30, val2)
(03.01 14:10, val3)
(05.01 02:59, val2)

Тут сортировка зашита в колонку begin_ts, и никаких проблем с обработкой данных в такой структуре не будет.
